# where can i find usage example plus docs on java.net.urlconnection

Tags: java

I specifically require usage examples/docs for the functions "getContent" and "getContent(class)" which are part of java.net.urlconnection ... I tried googling, but could not find any good examples for these functions...

Comment: Here's [the javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getContent%28%29). Bookmark it.

Answer (score 0):

The Java Documentation for class `URLConnection` is at http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html

and at the oracle site is a tutorial how to work with URLConnection. maybe it helps you:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html